# Состав сказуемого

Tags: сказуемые

Входит ли второе существительное в состав сказуемого?

> Среда - **день *недели***. Среда - **место *обитания***.

Comment: Тема вопроса неясно обозначена. Нужно пояснить свою точку зрения: почему вы допускаете возможность вхождения второго существительного в состав сказуемого?

Comment: Считаю неделимым сочетанием.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Тема несвободных сочетаний была в школьной программе? Теория там довольно сложная. В каком объеме ее дают в школе и по каким учебникам, я не очень представляю.

Comment: По учебнику Литневской.

Comment: Изучить эту тему по Литневской сложно, там дается только самое общее представление. Фразеологически свободное, но синтаксически связанное словосочетание может иметь следующее строение: б) существительное с зависимыми от него словами, если само существительное малоинформативно, а смысловой центр высказывания находится именно в зависимых от имени словах (само существительное в этом случае может быть выброшено из предложения почти без потери смысла): Он лучший ученик в классе.

Comment: Среда день недели. Что отсюда можно выбросить без потери смысла?  Здесь речь может идти о недостаточной информативности слова «день»  в конкретном предложении, но тогда следует рассуждать  о контекстуально несвободных сочетаниях. А у Литневской ничего этого нет.

Comment: Эта тема вообще не для школьников. Так можно взять любое слово и давать ему определение по словарю. Стол — предмет мебели. Мебель — предметы комнатной обстановки. Предмет — всякое конкретное, материальное явление, воспринимаемое органами чувств и мышлением как нечто существующее особо. Явление — внешнее выражение сущности предметов, процессов; непосредственное отражение вещи в чувственном восприятии. И т.д.   В этом тексте много слов, которые можно считать малоинформативными. Но эта тема явно не для школы.

Comment: @Просто понимаете. В некоторых заданиях попадаются такие конструкции: "Итак, технически это письменная речь". Как ученик должен понять, что сказуемое " письменная речь", а не просто речь. Конечно, составили не просят соотносить основы, представленные в этом предложении, с основами вариантов, но сам факт (данное предложение является сложным: это предполагает, что основы нужно выделять).

Comment: "Монолог - искусственная форма речи". Что должен включить в сказуемое школьник? Форма? Форма речи? Все это очень смотрится запутанно.

Comment: Желательно  задавать на форуме конкретное предложение, которое вызвало затруднение.  Если в школе не проходили подробно эту тему, то лучше считать сказуемым слово "форма". Также возможна проверка: Монолог  – искусственная речевая форма. Тогда получается,я, что нет тесной связи слов в сочетании "форма речи".

Comment: @Sharon Дело еще и в оценивании. Непонятно, что на уме у составителей. Примеров с такими неделимыми сочетаниями в вариантах я не встречала, но там часто встречаются количественно-именное сочетания и сочетания с именами собственными. например "Шапка Мономаха".

Comment: Это верно. Наверное, школьные педагоги должны давать пояснения. На экзаменах, вероятно, проверяется средний уровень знаний относительно сочетаний, а не особо продвинутый.

Comment: Составные  имена собственные (Шапка Мономаха) – это всегда один член предложения. Это один конкретный предмет. Пять книг - один член предложения.

Comment: Да, просто об этом говорится в учебниках по русскому (есть в типах), а таких, как "письменная речь", нет.

Comment: Речь бывает письменная и устная, это определения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второе существительное входит в состав сказуемого в обоих предложениях.

Одинокое "место" — это команда пёсику. Или абстракция: два места в партере. Дядь, уступи место, а не то. "Есть такое место — это Сьерра-Маэстра, там глухою ночью — утро воскресло..."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в случае со средой-днём сложнее: среда ведь действительно день (свободное слово), о чём [поёт Высоцкий](http://www.bards.ru/archives/part.php?id=15261), но она же и день недели.

> Ну вот, исчезла дрожь в руках,
>
> Теперь — наверх!
>
> Ну вот, сорвался в пропасть страх —
>
> Навек, навек.
>
> Для остановки нет причин —
>
> Иду, скользя…
>
> И в мире нет таких вершин,
>
> Что взять нельзя.

---

> Среди нехоженых путей
>
> Один — пусть мой.
>
> Среди невзятых рубежей
>
> Один — за мной.
>
> А имена тех, кто здесь лег,
>
> Снега таят…
>
> Среди непройденных дорог
>
> Одна — моя.

---

> Здесь голубым сияньем льдов
>
> Весь склон облит,
>
> И тайну чьих-нибудь следов
>
> Гранит хранит…
>
> И я гляжу в свою мечту
>
> Поверх голов
>
> И свято верю в чистоту
>
> Снегов и слов.

---

> И пусть пройдет немалый срок —
>
> Мне не забыть,
>
> Как здесь сомнения я смог
>
> В себе убить.
>
> В тот день шептала мне вода:
>
> "Удач всегда…"
>
> **А день… какой был день тогда?**
>
> **Ах да — среда!..**
>
> 1969 г.

Answer (score 2):

***Среда — день** недели. **Среда — место** обитания.*

1. Я считаю,  что  **не следует** включать существительное в состав сказуемого, так как эти сочетания **не являются связанными** (несвободными).

В данном случае это **несогласованные определения в форме Р.п.**

2. Попробую привести доказательства не по грамматике (уже обсуждали, хотя напрасно!), а **по смыслу.**

(1) *Среда — **день** недели.*

*Среда — **середина** недели. Среда — **мой любимый** день.* Мы видим, что формы "недели" в этих сообщениях нет. Тогда какое же здесь связанное сочетание "день недели"?

(2) Среда — **место** обитания.

*Лес — это не среда обитания барсука, а **место обитания**.* Следует **[различать](https://uchi.ru/otvety/questions/chem-otlichaetsya-ponyatie-sreda-obitaniya-ot-ponyatiya-mesto-obitaniya-poyasnite-na-konk)** эти понятия.

Можно сказать: **среда** обитания или **место** обитания, тогда почему надо считать связанным сочетание "место обитания"?

**P.S.** Как я понимаю, мы здесь обсуждаем правильность ответов **на ОГЭ** (9-й класс), поэтому надо принимать **ОТВЕТСТВЕННЫЕ решения.**

Скорее всего, в 9-м классе дается **перечень стандартных связанных сочетаний** (числовые обороты, имена собственные, составные сказуемые и т.д.). Вряд ли следует самостоятельно анализировать **другие варианты** —  это не уровень незаконченной средней школы. **Учитель**  должен давать консультации по этой теме.

И я думаю, что включение существительного в состав сказуемого будет **ОШИБКОЙ.**  Если мое мнение неверно, то хотелось бы услышать мнение **других участников тоже.**

Comment: Если исходить из школьной программы, я с вами согласен. Если уровень выше, то все же я бы включил зависимое слово в состав сказуемого.

Comment: Я не уверена, это надо доказывать. Семантически недостаточные слова обычно  могут образовывать контекстуально несвободные сочетания.  Вот у Кустовой перечень этих слов: человек, люди, мужчина, женщина, вещь, дело, занятие, вопрос, место, время и др.  Слово день? Это вряд ли. Слово место? Как вариант, есть пример: Наш сад - место особенное. Но это не в каждом предложении. Например:  На столе больше нет места. И это должны анализировать ученики 9-го класса?

Comment: Мне кажется, на такие вопросы должны отвечать специалисты, которые занимаются проблемами обучения и составления учебных программ. И вообще предлагаю этот вопрос ЗАКРЫТЬ.